# How point multiple domains to one website

Tags: redirect, dns, hosting, nameservers

I barely know about DNS things as I am a developer. I need to point multiple domains say 50 from different registrars to my website just by updating nameservers on those domains. Just like godaddy or https://eftymarket.com/Olki.com/ do. I have tried updating the nameserver but it does not help.

Comment: Can you give some more information on what you have tried? Have you tried DNS records?

Comment: No i just updated the nameserver assuming it would redirect to my website nothing more than that

Comment: And what is your problem? You are not asking a question.

Comment: I have application in xyz.com and if type a.com it should resolve to xyz.com.I update a.com(without any application) with same nameserver like xyz.com I cannot add virtualhost as i have lots of domains.I dont know what else to be done

Comment: You can add a DNS records for your domains.

Comment: I cant just add DNS records in 50  domains.This number may increase in future.

Comment: The only sane way to point domain name to a webserver is by using DNS records.